# How to create a Stripe subscription with a variable quantity?

Tags: javascript, flask, stripe-payments

Right now I'm successfully creating a **Stripe** subscription that has a hardcoded quantity:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.create(email=request.form['stripeEmail'], source=request.form['stripeToken'])

# For the moment, change the quantity parameter for each customer
subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
    customer = customer.id,
    items = [
        {
            'plan': 'plan_*************',
            'quantity': 7,
        },
    ],
)
```

The idea would be to obtain that value for `quantity` from the frontend. I already have a selector that sets the quantity value programmatically and I'm actually using it to print variable amounts in **Stripe** Checkout:

```
<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "{{pub_key}}",
    image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
    locale: "auto",
    zipCode: true,
    token: function(token) {
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
      // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("customButton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var quantity = document.getElementsByName("selectedQuantity")[0];
    var text = quantity.options[quantity.selectedIndex].text;
    // Open Checkout with further options:
    handler.open({
      name: "Company, Inc.",
      description: text + " Subscriptions",
      amount: 900 * text
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation:
  window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

Notice that I'm getting the public key from the backend, but I don't know how to retrieve the quantity value from the frontend in the backend.

How do I do that?

**EDIT:**

When I wasn't using a custom Checkout integration I had a form that would do this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('pay') }}" method="POST">
```

But there is no form here, so I'm not sure what should the next step be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you submitting the token to your backend server(i.e. how have you implemented the `token` function)? Once you've done that, you can just submit the quantity in the same way.

One way to do this might be to use a form, add the Stripe token to a hidden input in that form, and then submit it with Javascript.

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/53u96kvw/

Or if you don't have a form at all, you can make an AJAX request with the same information : https://jsfiddle.net/kcp12o3z/

Comment: Ok just one more question: I was previously getting the mail and token on the flask file this way: customer = stripe.Customer.create(email=request.form['stripeEmail'], source=request.form['stripeToken']) but it's not working anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm printing request.form which has a token and a selected quantity, but not the email. What am I missing?

Comment: The `email` field is [present](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#required) on the value you get in the token function, you need to pass that along to your backend too. https://jsfiddle.net/94vaf0hn/